# Firefox ES6, get class constructor name

Tags: javascript, class, firefox, ecmascript-6, spidermonkey

I have problems getting the name of the constructor when using ES6 classes in Firefox. In Chromium it works fine, but Firefox seem to have some kind of bug? In Firefox I only get an empty string back. Anyone that knows of a workaround?

```
class MyClass {}
let a = new MyClass();
console.log(a.constructor.name);
```

Comment: So, when you access `MyClass.name` first, it works. When you access  `.constructor.name` first, it's a blank string. Weird, I'm guessing bug. Here's a Fiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/gveopgu8/

Comment: These issues may have some relation: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1192412 https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1280042

Comment: Maybe some good news, I cannot reproduce in Firefox Developer Edition (based on 50.0), so it may have already been fixed in an upcoming version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a bug (according to the comment below).

It appears that specifying an explicit constructor exhibits the correct behavior in Firefox (even the latest version 48).

```js
class MyClassWithConstructor {
  constructor() {
    console.log("Explicit Constructor")
  }
}

class MyClassWithoutConstructor {}

$('#with').click(function() {
 let tmp = new MyClassWithConstructor();
 alert("MyClassWithConstructor name = " + tmp.constructor.name);
})

$('#without').click(function() {
 let tmp = new MyClassWithoutConstructor();
 alert("MyClassWithConstructor name = " + tmp.constructor.name);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id=with>With Constructor</button>

<button id=without>Without Constructor</button>
```

Here's a link to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jc7g5crp/

Comment: It's a ES6 feature and appears to be a bug in FF.